# ssh to a pc under mobile network

Tags: ssh

My friend is using internet using mobile internet(Airtel). I want to ssh to his pc. I know his ip address and the name servers of his network. How can I ssh to his pc?

Comment: Have you tried running `ssh ipaddress`, where `ipaddress` is his IP address?

Comment: Does the address it shows on his device (network icon -> Information -> IP address) look something like this: `10.*.*.*` or `192.168.*.*`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check first if your friend have a real public IP Address and not a NAT  private IP Address (10.x.x.x or 172.16-31.x.x or 192.168.x.x)

If he has, you are in luck and you can try

```
ssh user@ipaddress
```

But most Telco operators do "Carrier grade NAT" in there mobile networks to hide a lot of costumers behind the same IP. In such a network a SSH Connection ist not direct possible because you can't open the relevant SSH port.